# PHP IMAP Receive Attachment from Microsoft Exchange Server

Tags: php, outlook, exchange-server, imap

Hello my client has asked me to make a website using PHP using which he can read/reply all his emails from all his accounts. Now he has a company account on Microsoft Exchange Server, I am using PHP imap_open to get emails from the mail-servers, I am able to get Email Attachments from Gmail account but I am not able to retrieve attachments from Microsoft Exchange server accounts. No error is getting generated so I am not sure what is wrong. Do I need to write some kind of special code in order to retrieve Attachments from Microsoft Exchange server email accounts?

Also a similar problem persists when trying to send emails, I am able to send emails from the PHP system using Gmail SMTP details, but not with Microsoft Exchange server

I am still researching but a little help would be much appreciated, maybe if you can just point me in the right direction I'll be able to understand what is wrong with my code. I don't know much about what Microsoft Exchange server is or how it is different from other email providers like Gmail, so I would really appreciate if you can just point me in the right direction.

The attachment retrieval code is working fine for Gmail accounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding SMTP mail sending problem for outlook server. I had the same problem, the problem is with the PORT Number.

Use `Port:587` instead of `Port:25` or any other options... I have been sending from Outlook with this port and I am successful every time.

And For IMAP attachment issue the solution is hidden in the case sensitivity...

If we look at the function `object imap_fetchstructure ( resource $imap_stream , int $msg_number)` which is generally responsible for fetching attachments.

What we get for Gmail And Others:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [type] => 1
    [encoding] => 0
    [ifsubtype] => 1
    [subtype] => MIXED
    [ifdescription] => 0
    [ifid] => 0
    [ifdisposition] => 0
    [ifdparameters] => 0
    [ifparameters] => 1
    [parameters] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [attribute] => BOUNDARY    // Notice Here...
                    [value] => b1_04114a96a39b7789f88fdabc7feadc61
                )

        )

    [parts] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [type] => 0
                    [encoding] => 1
                    [ifsubtype] => 1
                    [subtype] => HTML
                    [ifdescription] => 0
                    [ifid] => 0
                    [lines] => 20
                    [bytes] => 597
                    [ifdisposition] => 0
                    [ifdparameters] => 0
                    [ifparameters] => 1
                    [parameters] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [attribute] => CHARSET   // Notice Here...
                                    [value] => iso-8859-1
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [type] => 5
                    [encoding] => 3
                    [ifsubtype] => 1
                    [subtype] => JPEG
                    [ifdescription] => 0
                    [ifid] => 0
                    [bytes] => 266988
                    [ifdisposition] => 1
                    [disposition] => ATTACHMENT     // Notice Here...
                    [ifdparameters] => 1
                    [dparameters] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [attribute] => FILENAME    // Notice Here...
                                    [value] => oIROo0jJDb-15.jpg
                                )

                        )

                    [ifparameters] => 1
                    [parameters] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [attribute] => NAME    // Notice Here...
                                    [value] => oIROo0jJDb-15.jpg
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

What We Get for OUTLOOK:

```
 1
    [encoding] => 0
    [ifsubtype] => 1
    [subtype] => MIXED
    [ifdescription] => 0
    [ifid] => 0
    [ifdisposition] => 0
    [ifdparameters] => 0
    [ifparameters] => 1
    [parameters] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [attribute] => boundary
                    [value] => b1_df2cd0669f50efc788d5aecfdded4957
                )

        )

    [parts] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [type] => 0
                    [encoding] => 1
                    [ifsubtype] => 1
                    [subtype] => HTML
                    [ifdescription] => 0
                    [ifid] => 0
                    [lines] => 23
                    [bytes] => 729
                    [ifdisposition] => 0
                    [ifdparameters] => 0
                    [ifparameters] => 1
                    [parameters] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [attribute] => charset    // Notice Here...
                                    [value] => iso-8859-1
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [type] => 5
                    [encoding] => 3
                    [ifsubtype] => 1
                    [subtype] => JPEG
                    [ifdescription] => 0
                    [ifid] => 0
                    [bytes] => 266988
                    [ifdisposition] => 1
                    [disposition] => attachment    // Notice Here...
                    [ifdparameters] => 1
                    [dparameters] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [attribute] => filename    // Notice Here...
                                    [value] => cqLaQAZSei-15.jpg
                                )

                        )

                    [ifparameters] => 1
                    [parameters] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [attribute] => name    // Notice Here...
                                    [value] => cqLaQAZSei-15.jpg
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
?>
```

So now, generally for fetching attachments somewhere we use an if statement for checking if there is any attachments in that part of the email. For this context I would refer to [PHP IMAP Library Part 1](http://www.sitepoint.com/exploring-phps-imap-library-1/) And [PHP IMAP Library Part 2](http://www.sitepoint.com/exploring-phps-imap-library-2/)... The Fetching Attachment function is in the Part 2 of the Tutorial.

Get Attachment Function:

```
function getAttachments($imap, $mailNum, $part, $partNum) {
    $attachments = array();

    if (isset($part->parts)) {
        foreach ($part->parts as $key => $subpart) {
            if($partNum != "") {
                $newPartNum = $partNum . "." . ($key + 1);
            }
            else {
                $newPartNum = ($key+1);
            }
            $result = getAttachments($imap, $mailNum, $subpart,
                $newPartNum);
            if (count($result) != 0) {
                 array_push($attachments, $result);
             }
        }
    }
    else if (isset($part->disposition)) {
        if ($part->disposition == "ATTACHMENT") {    // Notice here...
            $partStruct = imap_bodystruct($imap, $mailNum,
                $partNum);
            $attachmentDetails = array(
                "name"    => $part->dparameters[0]->value,
                "partNum" => $partNum,
                "enc"     => $partStruct->encoding
            );
            return $attachmentDetails;
        }
    }

    return $attachments;
}
```

Notice the `if` statement inside the `else if` statement You can see it is comparing with capital `ATTACHMENT` but Outlook result has no Capital `ATTACHMENT` they have `attachment`. So instead of that line I'll recommend using: `strtoupper($part->disposition) == 'ATTACHMENT'`...

In this way we have the attachment working...

So the final function should be:

```
function getAttachments($imap, $mailNum, $part, $partNum) {
    $attachments = array();

    if (isset($part->parts)) {
        foreach ($part->parts as $key => $subpart) {
            if($partNum != "") {
                $newPartNum = $partNum . "." . ($key + 1);
            }
            else {
                $newPartNum = ($key+1);
            }
            $result = getAttachments($imap, $mailNum, $subpart,
                $newPartNum);
            if (count($result) != 0) {
                 array_push($attachments, $result);
             }
        }
    }
    else if (isset($part->disposition)) {
        if (strtoupper($part->disposition) == "ATTACHMENT") {
            $partStruct = imap_bodystruct($imap, $mailNum,
                $partNum);
            $attachmentDetails = array(
                "name"    => $part->dparameters[0]->value,
                "partNum" => $partNum,
                "enc"     => $partStruct->encoding
            );
            return $attachmentDetails;
        }
    }

    return $attachments;
}
```

I hope that will fix the problem... Because it did for me...

Thank you...